# CodePipeline + Beanstalk Connection Refused React + Express Apps

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'll lay this out below in detail:

### Goal

A React front-end game that uses `socket.io` to transfer game state data between players on the Express server.

### Setup

After finding that it would be impossible/a real work-around to have both React/Express on an Amplify instance, I decided to move to CodePipeline + CodeDeploy to Beanstalk.

I have the Source coming from GitHub, a CodeBuild step, and then CodeDeploy. The CodeBuild should basically just compile based on my `buildspec.yml` below:

```
version: 0.2
  frontend:
    phases:
      preBuild:
        commands:
          - npm ci
      build:
        commands:
          - npm run build
   artifacts:
     baseDirectory: build
     files:
       - '**/*'
   cache:
     paths:
```

Although this is calling `npm run build`, which I'm not sure A) The CodeBuild/CodeDeploy will try to do with `node start` or B) If this will kick off my react-scripts build in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --production",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I'm assuming I want it to build the webpack bundle in CodeBuild, then CodeDeploy will call the proper run command, but it seems black boxed? Is there another config file?

### Runtime Errors

I get Connection Refused, although my `server.js` file defaults to localhost and 8080:

```
var hostname = process.env.IP || 'localhost';
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

Web.std.out.log:

```
Sep 20 18:10:10 ip-172-31-41-5 web: > MyApp@0.1.0 start /var/app/current
Sep 20 18:10:10 ip-172-31-41-5 web: > react-scripts start
Sep 20 18:10:12 ip-172-31-41-5 web: #033[34mâ„¹#033[39m #033[90mï½¢wdsï½£#033[39m: Project is running at http://172.31.41.5/
Sep 20 18:10:12 ip-172-31-41-5 web: #033[34mâ„¹#033[39m #033[90mï½¢wdsï½£#033[39m: webpack output is served from
Sep 20 18:10:12 ip-172-31-41-5 web: #033[34mâ„¹#033[39m #033[90mï½¢wdsï½£#033[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /var/app/current/public
Sep 20 18:10:12 ip-172-31-41-5 web: #033[34mâ„¹#033[39m #033[90mï½¢wdsï½£#033[39m: 404s will fallback to /
Sep 20 18:10:12 ip-172-31-41-5 web: Starting the development server...
```

Ngnix error.log: `2020/09/18 03:07:30 [error] 4436#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.40.133, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.41.5"`

Lot of moving parts so I'm sure there are several missteps here, not sure which is which.

Comment: The first step to troubleshoot if to check if you can deploy your app successfully without CodePipeline. Just plain Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: I am able to run the `npm build` and `serve -s build` locally but Beanstalk fails.

Comment: This might be it, from standalone Beanstalk log: `[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [check Procfile]. Stop running the command. Error: node.js may have issues starting. Please provide a package.json file or add server.js/app.js file in source bundle`

Comment: EB will look for package.json file. If you want to use other command to start your app, you can provide your own in `Procfile`. I would have to provide an answer to write more details due to limited space in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

By [default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html) EB will look for `package.json` to run your application. If it is missing, and will use use [script](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-package-json-guide#scripts) option in your `package.json` to start your application. For example, if you start sample node.js application that EB provides, the file is:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Elastic-Beanstalk-Sample-App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

If you don't provide `package.json` nor `Procfile` (other option, see below) EB will expect `app.js` or `server.js` to be present to start your application.

If you don't want to use `package.json`, you can also use `Procfile` to tell EB how to start your application.

> When you don't provide a Procfile, Elastic Beanstalk runs npm start if you provide a package.json file. If you don't provide that either, Elastic Beanstalk looks for the file app.js or server.js, in this order, and runs it.

Example in your case could be

```
web: serve -s build
```

Comment: I was able to confirm in `eb-engine.log` that the Procfile was being uptaken and the two processes I've specified for the front-end/back-end are ran. The only other error that might be causing it to fail before logs are output is a `The deployment didn't install a specific Node.js version`. Do I need to specify this always in `package.json`? I'm surprised it doesn't automatically install the Node platform version specified when setting up EB.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error on that first process, `See "systemctl status web.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`. It might be tough accessing those control commands because I have been having trouble connecting to my EC2 instances. The process command is `web: serve -s build`

Comment: @A13X What's wrong with connecting to the EC2 instance? For the node version, maybe you set somewhere to use non-default version for your environment?

Comment: Locally I've been using 12.16.1, I added it to package.json and that error seems to have cleared up. But now the first process is erroring, maybe because I don't have `serve` installed somehow?

Comment: Can you spinup new EB environment where you can login using ssh. This way would allow you to investigate from the inside what packages are installed, why `systemctl status web.service` fails. Thanks for accepting:-)

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get SSH in to even a new EC2 instance, although I'm setting a lot of things to default. I have the private key on my local machine and try to putty/pageant in. I tried installing `serve` in `package.json` but that didn't seem to help. And no problem, at least this got the ball rolling.

Comment: Okay I decided to scrap any fancy commands in Proc and just do `npm start`. That at least got my Deploy green. Still have a 502 Gateway Ngnix error though when navigating to URL. Probably looking for the wrong port/need to forward it? I tried 3000,5000,8000,8080 in my browser.

Comment: In the browser, port is 80. But your app I think should run on port 5000. But can you ssh now to the instance now?. This is bigger issue in my view why you can't access it. You can make new question for it with relevant details.

Comment: Okay now I am getting a `Cannot get /` from the url at least. It looks like it runs commands for both express and React, but I see `Something is already running on port 8080.` from the React/web process. Is it continually calling `npm start`? Still getting `Connection refused` for Ngnix log (also 8080). Maybe they run on same port? But I get the `Cannot get /` from port 80 (regular url).